# Property 'formatToParts' does not exist on type 'DateTimeFormat'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using angular 9 with a tsconfig set to es6.

```
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
```

I am trying to do the following :

```
    static formatForDisplay(date: Date): string {
        const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' });
        const [{ value: mo }, , { value: da }, , { value: ye }] = dtf.formatToParts(date);
        return `${mo} ${da}, ${ye}`;
    }
```

but typescript complain about when I compile (but not in visual code)

> Property 'formatToParts' does not exist on type 'DateTimeFormat'

why so? it does exist

Comment: add 'DateTimeFormat' type to dtf like **const dtf : DateTimeFormat = ...................**?

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23691 seems it was fixed, maybe you need to check your TS version?
Also, you can use it like this dtf['formatToParts'](date) as a quick workaround.

Comment: i use ts ignore, but I think the issue is still there. I will check on the github